# Open a DialogFragment from within a CustomView

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm working on one of my Android projects, trying to lessen the code inside my Activities. In one of them, I have CustomView (which just extends LinearLayout) that opens a DialogFrament when clicked. Now, the way I implement this is by overriding `onTouch()` in the activity and subsequently opening the DialogFrament from there. It looks something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (v.getId() == mCustomView.Id()) {
            mDialogFragment.show(mFragmentManager, "");
```

I'd like to move the process of opening the DialogFragment away from the activity and into the CustomView itself, but, the problem I have is that I can't get an instance of FragmentManager (by using `getSupportFragmentManager()`) in the CustomView. Is what I'm planning possible, or should I stick to the code that I have working? I'm doing this so my code looks cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Related question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072233/return-a-callback-open-a-dialogfragment-from-within-a-customview)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in your custom view you can call `getContext()` (which will be your activity) so then you can cast it to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and call `getSupportFragmentManager()` from there.

So this should do it.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) getContext();
FragmentManager fm = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072233/return-a-callback-open-a-dialogfragment-from-within-a-customview)