# Return a callback (Open a DialogFragment from within a CustomView)

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

This is related to my previous question here: [Open a DialogFragment from within a CustomView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061993/open-a-dialogfragment-from-within-a-customview/18062221?noredirect=1#18062221)

I now need to use a callback to return a value from my DialogFragment. I understand that something like this is commonly done:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public interface onMultipleSelectionFragmentCloseListener {
    public void onMultipleSelectionFragmentOkay();
}

onMultipleSelectionFragmentCloseListener mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (onMultipleSelectionFragmentCloseListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onMultipleSelectionFragmentCloseListener");
    }
}
....
// to use it
mListener.onMultipleSelectionFragmentOkay();
```

That's the case when you want a Activity to implement and receive the callback. But, what if I want a custom view to do that (such as in my previous question)?

Answer (score -1):

You do the same thing-  you create an interface like above.  You keep a reference to a variable of that interface type.  Then you have some function registerListener that takes a listener object and stores it so you can call it later.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I do the "Then you have some function registerListener that takes a listener object and stores it so you can call it later" part? Actually, the problem I have here is this line:  `mListener = (onMultipleSelectionFragmentCloseListener) activity;` because it takes in an activity. Now, I don't know how to replace that `activity` with my custom view. P.S. I really need to take a Java course.

Comment: You're only taking an Activity here because the function onAttach requires it.  Your View won't have an onAttach function, that's a fragment thing.  Instead, you'll write a function named RegisterListener that will take a value with the type of your listener, then just assign it to the variable mListener.

Comment: Could you maybe post some pseudocode? I've got it working now by moving the try-catch block in `onCreate()`. I just passed the id of my custom view (I use it multiple times in the ui) into a bundle then I did this `mListener = (onMultipleSelectionFragmentCloseListener) this.getActivity().findViewById(ViewID);` in the try-catch block.

Comment: Really, if you still aren't understanding-  you need to learn what an interface is, what a class is, and how to use them in Java.  Continuing to go on without that knowledge is going to cost you more time than stopping now and learning the language.